# Sitecore WFFM installation error :- An item name cannot contain any of the following characters

Tags: wffm

I am using Sitecore version : Sitecore.NET 7.2 (rev. 140526) and 
Web form version 2.4.0 rev. 140117.

At the time of installing *Web Forms for Marketers* I am getting below error :

> An item name cannot contain any of the following characters:
>   /:?"<>|[]-

I have removed the value for the InvalidItemNameChars setting but still I am getting the same error.

```
<setting name="InvalidItemNameChars" value="" />
```

Comment: Verify that no other configs are patching this setting. The error string pulls the value directly from configs. Try running showconfig.

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable `ItemNameValidation`. Add a config file to `App_Config/Include` named `z.DisableItemNameValidation.config` and put this in it:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="ItemNameValidation">
        <patch:attribute name="value"></patch:attribute>
      </setting>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error is your `ItemNameValidation` setting includes a `-` (dash). The default OOTB setting does not include this value in this setting.

The WFFM package contains one or more items which include a dash in the item name. Most likely your project has overwritten the default `ItemNameValidation` hence the reason you are getting this error when trying to install the package. The changes are possibly as part of solution along with `encodeNameReplacements` replacing spaces with dashes for SEO friendly URLs and I've [blogged about this issue previously](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/07/13/seo-friendly-urls-in-sitecore-prevention-is-better-than-cure/).

The solution is either:

- Install the WFFM package on a clean Sitecore instance before deploying any of your solution specific customisations or,
- Revert the `ItemNameValidation` back to it's default value of `/:?"<>|[]` whilst you install the package using either a patch config or removing your custom config/setting.